# Blender getting sluggish with time

Tags: interface

ok...
let's try this again!

Newby here and i have a problem that is really really really annoying.

Blender becomes sluggish with time!

And i can't find a cause for it.

laptop has
8 gig
4 cores
4 Gh
While i run blender only 1 core is active around 1 Gh and rarely more.
Less than 4 gig of memory is occupied.

When i open the software it runs properly...
i click on any object, vertex, etc... and it lights up immediately.

But after about half an hour latter it can take more than a second for the item to light up.
And after a full hour it is beyond 5 second.

Someone suggested it could be the undo step???

if it was...
when i close the file and open a new one, the system is suppose to drops the old undo list and create a new one...
hence the system should then return to normal speed...

it doesn't!

Plus the lag time should not keep growing.

it does!

Therefore the problem must be something else.

I tried reinstalling the software a while back but it didn't solve the problem.

i didn't have that problem with...
3ds Max
maya
or Rhino (and i used a lot more undo step then, as i was beginning to teach myself 3d).

Having to close and reload the software every 30 minutes is truly annoying!

Does anyone have any usable ideal?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address raised the issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: Generally speaking this sounds like the symptoms "memory leak" something about Blender is leaving data behind that is building up over time and making it slow down. This a very hard to diagnose issue and not something we can solve here with a mere descrription

Comment: So what your saying is that no one here has any kind of ideal on how to resolve this issue and that i should just learn to live with it and not ask a site dedicated to this software for help! Truly futile.

Comment: We have a pretty solid idea of how to solve it, it is probably a bug and should be reported so a developer can fix it. That is if you can provide a reliable and reproducible way to recreate the issue. This is Q&A site run by volunteers, we are not programmers nor in any way associated with the Blender Foundation, decision making nor development process of the software.

Comment: That should have been the first and only answer. THAT make sense. I would love to report it to a developer but how exactly? Cause i have enough of a headache trying to teach myself how to achieve what i am trying to create, this having to close and reopen the software over and over is very annoying. Thank for that answer and if you can tell me how and where to report this.... if not... take care!

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1377/2217